# Python while string comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to debug some Python code of mine and I can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas why this keeps repeating if I input the correct argument for the direction input variable?

```
direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
while direction != "encode" or direction != "encrypt" or direction != "decrypt" or direction != "decode":
    print("Please put in a valid direction!\n")
    direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
```

Comment: Try `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Every possible string is either not "encode" or not "encrypt"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `and` instead of `or`. Alternatively, you might find the following more readable:

```py
while direction not in ('encode', 'encrypt', 'decrypt', 'decode'):
```

Comment: Thanks! Learning here as I go. Appreciate the help. That is much clearer now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")

method = ["encode", "encrypt", "decrypt", "decode"]

while direction not in method:
    print("Please put in a valid direction!\n")
    direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for while loop is not correct.
for example when you enter "decode" as input your `encode != true` is correct so loops continue
You can use this code:

```
direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
while direction not in {"encode", "encrypt", "decode", "decrypt"} :
    print("Please put in a valid direction:!")
    direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
```